# Mysql IF THEN without ELSE

Tags: mysql

In the SELECT i do some calculations (sum,min,ifnull,multiply and substraction) with a couple columns involved (lets call it someComplexCalc), and if that results smaller than 0 than i want it to turn 0.

The problem is i dont want to repeat the someComplexCalc to run twice in one line, because of performance loss. I want somekind of statement which only replaces the result if it is smaller than 0, otherwise it leaves it, just like how the IFNULL(statement,0) works, which have no THEN part.

With If statement i cant do that, nor with CASE

```
    
SELECT
  (IF someComplexCalc < 0, 0, someComplexCalc) AS result   #someComplexCal runs twice
  (IF someComplexCalc < 0, 0) AS result    #not working, than part is missing so it return NULL
```

Comment: I dont get answer so here is another example    <pre>SELECT (IF (5*4*3*2*1)  < 0, 0 , (5*4*3*2*1) ) AS result</pre> how can i avoid making mysql calculate that twice

Comment: I know i can accomplish this with subquery, but i want to avoid that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [greatest()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function instead of `if()` to return the greater of 0 or the complex calculation:

```
select greatest(complexcalc, 0) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

With *user-defined variables*:

```
SELECT if( (@x:=5*4*3*2*1)<0, 0, @x) x;
```